# gluUnProject - can't get correct values

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm making a call to gluUnProject (app is using GLES20). For the life of me I cannot get the value I'm looking for.

I have an object at (-9, 0, 0), so I need the result of gluUnProject to equal this somehow. The camera is at (0, 20, 4) and the near/far plane distances are (3, 100). I've even tried printing out the current matrices when the function is run (in this case the pixel position touched on screen is (160, 345), which is very near to the position of the object):

```
win: (160,345,0.0)
model: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
viewport: (0, 0, 1280, 720)
proj: (0.5625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.020202, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.020202, 0.0)
```

Near Plane:

```
obj: (-1.3333333, -0.041666687, -1.0, 1.0)
final: (-1.3333333, -0.041666687, -1.0)
```

Far plane:

```
obj: (-1.3333333, -0.041666687, -1.0, 0.00999999)
final: (-133.33345, -4.1666727, -100.0001)
```

Should I be using something calculated for the Z value here? If I supply a value around 0.864 I get approximately the right X value (-9), which doesn't really make sense to me. I can't find this value in any calculations. I've played with the numbers over and over and just can't make it all work together. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with gluUnProject.

The 3rd parameter is the depth of the desired point, in screen space (ie between 0 and 1, with 0 mapping to the near plane and 1 mapping to the far plane)

Since you don't know this value, you can't use this function.

If you're trying to implement picking, you should manually launch a ray and test intersections with your object (or use a collision/physics engine to do that for you).

Comment: Can I not calculate the depth? My near plane is 3, my far plane is 100, I know the exact position of all objects therefore I can calculate the distance from one object to any other object, as well as how far into the near/far plane it is given the distance.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly ? If you want the object's distance to the camera, just do (v1-v2).length()...

Comment: I think I was running under the assumption that I could calculate the depth of an object and just test that, instead of having to test many depths to check for an intersection. So now I am just calling unproject for a few different depths and checking for intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my unproject

```
glm::vec3 World::Unproject(glm::vec3 v){
  glm::mat4 pv = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix;
  glm::mat4 inv = glm::inverse(pv);
  glm::vec4 v4(v, 1.f);
  glm::vec4 r4 = inv * v4;
  glm::vec3 r(r4.x / r4.w, r4.y / r4.w, r4.z / r4.w);
  return r;
}
```

`v` is `(x,y,1.0)`

`-1.0 < x,y < 1.0`

Camera, Unproject(v) - defines ray
You can calculate distance to ray